# С# DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

Создал таблицу с помощью DataGridView в Visual Studio. После того как я введу значения в клетку и нажму Enter,оно перескакивает на другую клетку (выделяя ее)?Как сделать что бы оно не выделяло ни одну клетку после этого?

Comment: WinForms? WPF? Xamarin? ...

Comment: в Windows Forms

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй вот этот вариант

```
    private void dataGridView1_CurrentCellChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
    }
```